# Find accounts with more than N months of activity in a row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter accounts that have no consecutive activity for N months.

Example:

```
a100000001 | 2019-01-31 | NaN
           | 2019-02-28 | 40
           | 2019-03-31 | 30
           | 2019-04-30 | 50
-----------|------------|-----
a100000002 | 2019-01-31 | NaN
           | 2019-02-28 | NaN
           | 2019-03-31 | 20
           | 2019-04-30 | NaN
-----------|------------|-----
...        |            |
```

The result for N=3 consecutive months will look like this:

```
a100000001 | 2019-01-31 | NaN
           | 2019-02-28 | 40
           | 2019-03-31 | 30
           | 2019-04-30 | 50
-----------|------------|-----
...        |            |
```

where account "a100000002" was ignored.

I tried `df[df.rolling(3)['amount'].min().notna()]` but it also removes the NaN rows from the desired accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
df.groupby('account').filter(lambda g: (g['date'].dt.month.diff() <= n).all())
```